# Complex join quick by itself, slow as a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to help a coworker with a large complex query.  One of the joins returns the data correctly but performs poorly.  If we run the join by itself, it returns in seconds.  As part of the larger query, it takes forever if it ever works at all.

Can someone provide some pointers on how to optimize this?  Would sub selects perform better than joins?

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cip.CaseID, dispo_sub2.CaseTitle, DATEPART(YEAR,MAX(cip.DispoDt)) DispoYr, cip.DispoDt, cip.DispoCode, cip.DispoDesc, LTRIM(rea.Reasons) Reasons, cip.CountInvPersAddDt 
       FROM 
           (SELECT dispo_sub.CaseID, dispo_sub.CaseTitle, dispo_sub.DispoDt, MAX(cip_sub2.CountInvPersAddDt) LastAddDt
           FROM
                    (SELECT cip_sub.CaseID, c.casetitle, MAX(cip_sub.DispoDt) DispoDt
                    FROM jw50_CountInvPers cip_sub 
                        INNER JOIN jw50_Case c on c.CaseID = cip_sub.CaseID
                    WHERE c.CaseTypeCode = 'TY706'
                        AND cip_sub.DispoDt IS NOT NULL
                        AND cip_sub.DispoCode IS NOT NULL 
                    GROUP BY cip_sub.CaseID, c.CaseTitle) dispo_sub
                INNER JOIN jw50_CountInvPers cip_sub2 on cip_sub2.CaseID = dispo_sub.CaseID and cip_sub2.DispoDt = dispo_sub.DispoDt
           GROUP BY dispo_sub.CaseID, dispo_sub.CaseTitle, dispo_sub.DispoDt) dispo_sub2
        INNER JOIN jw50_CountInvPers cip on cip.CaseID = dispo_sub2.CaseID AND cip.DispoDt = dispo_sub2.DispoDt AND cip.CountInvPersAddDt = dispo_sub2.LastAddDt
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                  c_sub.CaseID,
                  STUFF((SELECT '; ' + ConditionTypeDesc
                    FROM jw50_Condition con            
                    WHERE con.CaseID = c_sub.CaseId
                    ORDER BY ConditionTypeDesc
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [Reasons]
                  FROM jw50_Case c_sub
                  GROUP BY c_sub.CaseID) rea on rea.CaseID = dispo_sub2.CaseID
       GROUP BY cip.CaseID, dispo_sub2.CaseTitle, cip.DispoDt, cip.DispoCode, cip.DispoDesc, rea.Reasons, cip.CountInvPersAddDt) dispo on dispo.CaseID = c.CaseID
```

Comment: Well, you can try to "dump" output of subquery into temporary table and join to this table instead of subquery.

Comment: Also a comparing look at the execution plans of both the simple and the complex query might provide further information of where the problem is located.

Comment: What's the query plan looking like?  Might not be using the best join operator.  Might do better with a temp table or a query hint, but hard to say.

Comment: I wish I could view the plan:  "SHOWPLAN permission denied in database..."

Comment: In general, does a sub select perform better than a join when needing a single value or does it vary?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, I ended up going with a temp table as all other attempts failed.  Seems dirty but it works and returns quickly.  Good enough for now.